# Can you gain access to a Microsoft Account from a Local Account in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, security, user-accounts

When you are using an Administrator account, you can change other Local Accounts password in Control Panel and have full access to the account.
However if it's a MS Account there is no option to do that.

Does this mean I can let other people using my PC with a Local Admin account, and not afraid of that my App Data from main MS Account can be leaked somehow?

I know that raw data stored in disk can be view, I'm just worry about people logging in my account and using app services that I already signed in, such as Windows Store, Office 365, ...

Comment: If you give them an Administrator account they can access the AppData folder to any user

Comment: The whole point of an Administrator account is that is is unrestricted. If you don't want other people accessing your data don't give them an Administrator account.

Comment: I'm aware of raw data on disk like in AppData folder. Maybe I should change the question to something like "Is your email credential, the one that you used to create your MS Account, protected if you lost your laptop?"

Answer (score 0):

With local admin account the user can do anything, like install keylogger, auto screen captures, etc.

Like  Ramhound comment - the user can grab cookies from your browsers and use it to steal your microsoft sessions